# How to add Scroll View to a Linear Layout which is having Linear layouts again inside it

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a Linear layout and again inside the linear layout I have some list off apps which are designed using Linear layouts, Now I want to scroll this list of Linear layouts. Please help me how to achieve this.

Comment: It is unclear what you want to achieve from your description. Please add your attempt to your question. Or perhaps an illustration.

Comment: I have a Linear layout which is a parent under that I have a tool bar and 5 linear layouts again. Now I want to fix the toolbar and scroll only the linear layouts which in future may exceed more than 5.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add scroll view in LinearLayout, but there are many LinearLayouts in LinearLayout, scroll this list of layout, you can take a look:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<ScrollView android:id="@+id/scrollView1" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
              android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

              <!-- Content here -->

</LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

              <!-- Content here -->     
</LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
              <!-- Content here -->     
</LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
              <!-- Content here -->     
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Hi Cherry Bu,  if i add scroll view in such a way it's throwing me an exception that scroll view can have only one child element.

Comment: @nuggu, you can see that there is one scrollview, one Linearlayout in Scrollview, there are also four Linearlayout in this LinearLayout, so you don't get this expection, because Scrollview just have one child LinearLayout, this LinearLayout have four child  LinearLayout.